# Why $H^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega_-)\cap H^2(\Omega_+) \subset W^1_p(\Omega),\forall p>2$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a book and it says that:

Let $\Omega=\Omega_-\cup\Omega_+$. Define $X(\Omega)=H^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega_-)\cap H^2(\Omega_+)$. 
Then by the Sobolev embedding theorem, $X(\Omega)\subset W^1_p(\Omega)$, for any $p>2$.

I understand that $H^2(\Omega_\pm)\subset W^1_p(\Omega_\pm)$, for any $p>2$ follows from the Sobolev embedding theorem. But how come the statement hold for the whole domain $\Omega$? (since $W^1_p(\Omega)\subset H^1(\Omega),\forall p>2$).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For $f\in H^1(\Omega)$, you already know that the weak derivatives $f_\alpha := \partial^\alpha f$ exist on all of $\Omega$. Thus, you only need to show $f_\alpha \in L^p(\Omega)$. For this, it suffices to show (why?) $f\alpha \in L^p(\Omega_1)$ and $f_\alpha \in L^p(\Omega_2)$, which follows (apparently) from Sobolev embedding.

Comment: I might not say clearly but let $\Gamma=\Omega_-\cap\Omega_+$. Then as I understand $f\in X(\Omega)$ means $f\in H^2$ on each of $\Omega_\pm$ but may be only $H^1$ on $\Gamma$, not $H^2$ on it. So why does it suffice to show only $f_\alpha\in L^p(\Omega_-)$ and $f_\alpha\in L^p(\Omega_+)$ as you said? Thank you.

Comment: Note $|f_\alpha| \leq |f_\alpha| \cdot 1_{\Omega_+} + |f_\alpha| \cdot 1_{\Omega_-}$ and use the triangle inequality.